# Files Directory with Folder name and link to file creating a list

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory, directory-structure

```py
import os

for folderName, subFolders, fileNames in os.walk('C:\Home\Homework\Folders'):
    for file in fileNames:
        print(folderName, os.path.join(folderName, file))
```

Let's say that there are 3 folders Named One, Two, and Three that live in `C:\Home\Homework\Folders`.

I want a script that will create a list or table  such as:

| Folder | File Link |
| --- | --- |
| One | C:\Home\Homework\Folders\One\sample.pdf. |
| One | C:\Home\Homework\Folders\One\sample.txt |
| Two | C:\Home\Homework\Folders\Two\test1.pdf |
| Two | C:\Home\Homework\Folders\Two\test.csv |
| Three | C:\Home\Homework\Folders\Three\excel.xlsx |

My end goal is to export a list to a CSV file.

Comment: The Following script above I have tried using but I get stuck with creating a table list from my outcome.

Comment: Printing just displays the result in the console but doesn't save it. There are tons of ways to do this -- one way would be to collect a list of dictionaries and then write those dictionaries (two keys, "Folder", and "File Link"), to csv using [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). Or, just do the writing to CSV as you go (inside the inner for loop).

Comment: It's not super clear what you're attempting to do here though. Do you intend only to list the files one directory deep? I.e., all files in all subdirectories of `C:\Home\Homework\Folders`? Or do you intend to walk all sub-subdirectories? Will there be directories inside of `\One` for instance?

Comment: just upvoting to welcome you and because it’s a fun challenge. I would have started from Pathlib rather than os.walk() though, but each their own.

Comment: There are only different type of files (ex: pdf, excel, doc, jpg) within the One, Two, Three folders. There are no other folders inside the one, two, and three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, it's not clear to me whether you intend to walk subdirectories too. If so, you'll need a different solution.

I believe the following would achieve your task, however I did not test this code.

```py
import os
import csv


# Open your output file in a context manager
with open("my_output.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
    # Create a DictWriter instance using your output file and your desired header
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=("Folder", "File Link"))
    # Write the header to the file
    writer.writeheader()
    
    # Walk the target directory
    for folder_name, _, file_names in os.walk('C:\Home\Homework\Folders'):
        for file_name in file_names:
            file_link = os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)
            # Construct a dict whose keys match the `fieldnames` from earlier
            writer.writerow({"Folder": folder_name, "File Link": file_link})
```

Note the `_` in the top-level `for` loop. This is because, as I understand your question, you don't seem to want to walk the subdirectories. Using `_` as a variable name in Python is a conventional way of signifying to others reading your code that you do not care about the value and are not planning on using it anywhere. In this case `_` will be a list of directory names (or empty if there are no subdirectories in a given directory from `C:\Home\Homework\Folders`).

For example, suppose your file structure is

```
C/
  Home/
    Homework/
      Folders/
        One/
          sample.pdf
          sample.txt
          SomeSubDirectory/
            some_file.py
```

You wouldn't find `some_file.py` because we're not walking `SomeSubDirectory`.

Comment: your code worked!! I only did a small update adding this for "Folder" : os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(folder_name)) - I didn't want the whole folder link just the 'One' (in this case)

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure to mark my answer as accepted so that your question gets removed from the unanswered queue. Cheers!